# Update app, change preferences mode to Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE, will it update the existing preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In the current version of the app, I am accessing a shared preferences with Context.MODE_PRIVATE.
I am planning to update the app using the same shared preferences, but changing to Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE. What will happen in this case? Is it guaranteed that the current preferences data is still left intact, just the access mode is changed to world_readable?